# Replication on MongoDB using Visual Studio

Tags: c, mongodb, port

I am trying to replicate my data (a rar file) using mongodb and following this simple tutorial on mongodb website [mongodb_connections](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/connections.html) but its not working properly and giving run-time error of

> Unhandled exception at 0x577be130 in getting_started.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

I am using these commands

```
gridfs gfs[1];
gridfile gfile[1];
mongo conn[1];

mongo_replica_set_init(conn,"rs-dc-1");
mongo_replica_set_add_seed(conn,TEST_SERVER,TEST_PORT);
mongo_replica_set_add_seed(conn,TEST_SERVER,TEST_PORT+1);
mongo_replica_set_client(conn);
gridfs_init( conn, "test", "fs", gfs );
```

Can anyone guide me how i can setup the replication using visual studio and also as we know that all the data from mongodb will saves to

> C:\data\db

so  where will the new port data will save?

EDITED:

I tried to just connect to the replicated server with these simple commands

```
mongo conn[1];
mongo_replica_set_init(conn,"rs-dc-1");
mongo_replica_set_add_seed(conn,TEST_SERVER,TEST_PORT);
mongo_replica_set_add_seed(conn,TEST_SERVER,TEST_PORT+1);
res=mongo_replica_set_client(conn);
```

but it is still not connected and when i checked res is -1 means `MONGO_ERROR` is coming.

Do anyone has any idea about how to solve this?

EDITED-2:

This is the error i am getting

```
 MONGO_CONN_NO_PRIMARY,   /**< Can't find primary in replica set. Connection closed. */
```